# Orfeo Toolbox maps Pleiades wrong

Tags: imagery, digital-image-processing, orfeo-toolbox, orthorectification

I have a problem with Orfeo Toolbox (OTB) function OrthoRectification.

I have a Pleiades product which is an extract (not a whole scene) of a small area in the western hemisphere south of the equator (so all negative coordinates). When I run the image through the OTB OrthoRectification I receive all kinds of problems with the output. When I order the app to produce output in cartographic coordinates it looks like the proper data, but is mirror flipped w.r.t. the east-west axis, so it's above (north of) the proper area AND has wrong resolution. See the image, which more or less depicts what happens:

[image]

When I attempt to use WGS84 (geographic coords) the geometry gets completely twisted and all I get is a weirdly stretched triangle.

To date I have tried all options of the Orthoreg function but no set of parameters can fix the problems. I have read the metadata that came with the image and the extent is OK there, so I assume it's some kind of mistake in OTB handling of coordinates, but can't be sure. Did you have a similar problem and if yes how did you overcome it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pleiades and Spot 6/7 are ortho-ready products. You must tell the application to ignore the spatial metadata of the ratser: this md is only used to quick look the image without the need of doing a proper orthorectification... But causes y axis inversion.
You must use the "skipcarto" extended filename to ignore this wrong md in the raster image.

otbcli_OrthoRectification -io.in "/path/to/your/... /IMG_OR_DIM_file.TIF?&skipcarto=true"...

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. I am quite surprised, because the initial dataset has no georeference (the .tfw file is effectively zeros) and I can look up all the numbers needed for orthorectification (RPC etc), the purchase was also the "Primary product" from what I know, designated for people, who want to build their orthorectifications from the ground up.